# Counting rows for the column in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

My problem is simple. I have two tables

```
transaction_bodies
------------------
body_id
full_name
```

and the other one is

```
transaction_accounts
--------------------
account_id
body_id
account_name
```

Relation is `one to many`. One body can have multiple accounts. I am trying to create a query that counts the accounts that bodies have.

I tried this

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT count(*) as trans, tb.full_name 
      FROM transaction_accounts ta 
      LEFT JOIN transaction_bodies tb 
      ON tb.body_id = ta.body_id
   ) as row;
```

But this doesn't give the right result. Can anyone help me out with this?
And if can provide how to write sub-queries in Laravel that would be a appreciated much.

Comment: You have tagged this with Laravel, are you using Eloquent (Laravel models)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$result = DB::table('transaction_bodies')
         ->leftJoin('transaction_accounts as 
                              ta','transaction_bodies.body_id','ta.body_id')
          ->select(DB::raw('count(ta.account_id) AS trans'),'transaction_bodies.full_name')
          ->groupBy('transaction_bodies.body_id')

         ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `LEFT JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT tb.body_id, COUNT(ta.*)
FROM transaction_bodies LEFT JOIN transaction_accounts ta
ON tb.body_id = ta.body_id
GROUP BY tb.body_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple `LEFT JOIN` you can achieve it like

```
SELECT tb.full_name, COUNT(account_id) as accounts
FROM transaction_bodies tb LEFT JOIN transaction_accounts ta
ON tb.body_id = ta.body_id
GROUP BY tb.body_id;
```

In Laravel you can do it like with model

```
$accounts = Transaction_body::leftJoin('transaction_accounts as ta','transaction_bodies.body_id','ta.body_id')->groupBy('transaction_bodies.body_id')->get();
```

without model

```
$accounts = DB::table('transaction_bodies')->leftJoin('transaction_accounts as ta','transaction_bodies.body_id','ta.body_id')->groupBy('transaction_bodies.body_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            /**
             * Class Body
             */
            class Body extends Model
            {
                /**
                 * The database table used by the model.
                 *
                 * @var string
                 */
                protected $table = 'transaction_bodies';

                /**
                 * Get the accounts for the Transaction Body.
                 */
                public function accounts()
                {
                    return $this->hasMany(Account::class);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Class Account
             */
            class Account extends Model
            {
                /**
                 * The database table used by the model.
                 *
                 * @var string
                 */
                protected $table = 'transaction_accounts';

                /**
                 * Get the body that owns the account.
                 */
                public function body()
                {
                    return $this->belongsTo(Body::class);
                }
            }

            //usage
            $accounts = Body::find(1)->accounts;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many